# a guard of honor march to -- is "march" a verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

[Example](http://www.gettyimages.com/detail/news-photo/guard-of-honor-march-to-the-eternal-flame-on-nakhimov-news-photo/466492750):

> **A guard of honor march** to the eternal flame on Nakhimov Square on the memorial of the heroic defense of Sevastopol (1941-1942) as Crimeans celebrate the first anniversary of the referendum on March 16, 2014 in Sevastopol, Crimea. Today marks the first anniversary of the referendum which resulted in the annexation of the territory by Russia.

Is *march* used as a verb here? If so, then I must presume that *a guard of honor* is a plural noun, but it does not sound plural to me at all. Another way to look at this sentence, though, is treat *guard of honor* as an adjective describing *march*, but that can't be right either since structurally that part must be the main clause of this rather long sentence and would require a verb which would be missing. Which interpretation do you think is the correct one or am I completely wrong about all this?

Comment: It looks for like the issue here is about whether "a guard of honor" is singular or plural. (As you might already know, a guard can also mean "a group of guards".) I remember I ran into something similar, like "A set of problems are ...", before. I'd better leave whether it's fine or not for others to decide.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[A guard of honour](http://www.yourdictionary.com/guard-of-honour), according to *yourdictionary*, is:

> A group of people (especially military), arranged in one or more rows, at a ceremony to honour, or a visit by, an important person.

It is not uncommon to treat nouns that represent groups of individuals as plural nouns, even when the noun itself is strictly singular, especially when referring to an action undertaken by the individuals in the group (in this case, the members of the guard of honour do the marching.)

So *march* is a verb, and it is plural.The sentence

> A guard of honor march as Crimeans celebrate.

follows the same pattern as

> A child plays as her mother watches

---

For more detail on the use of plural or singular verbs with group nouns, see [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/collective-nouns-and-subject-verb-agreement-general-rule-or-arbitrary).

Comment: beat me to it! and I only registered to answer too damn you!

Comment: So, let me sum things up. Some think it's a noun, but some think it's a verb. Who's right? Go figure.

Comment: @CookieMonster: if it is a noun, there is a verb missing in the sentence. This is usually considered to be a grammatical error, although it is acceptable in headlines. This does not seem to be a headline. It _may_ be a style choice by the author, but seeing _march_ as a verb has no such issues. Except the use of _guard of honour_ as a plural, which is not as common in all dialects, but certainly acceptable in all.

Comment: There are very similar structures in which march might be a noun, such as "A guard of honour march took place to celebrate...". But that is not the case here.

Comment: @oerkelens Oops. my mistype.

Answer (score 3):

March is a verb: to walk with regular or measured tread.  The guard of honor (plural noun, as you suggested) are marching.

Answer (score 2):

*March* is used as a noun here.  The sentence is describing what's in the picture above it.  It's a picture of a march.  *Guard of honour* is an adjective describing the type of march.  Everything else in the sentence is providing further detail about the march: where, when and why.

Since the sentence is a caption for a picture, there is no need for a verb.

Alternatively, *march* could be a verb here, and *guard of honour* the noun.  In which case, *guard of honour* is being treated as a plural noun because it's a collection of individual people.  It's an unusual usage, but having read the sentence a few more times, I believe this is the correct interpretation.

Comment: Except that there is then no verb in the sentence.

Comment: ssav, That makes perfect sense! @WhatRoughBeast A title of a picture (or anything, for that matter) doesn't always need a verb. (See also: [Headlinese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).)

Comment: @DamkerngT. but this is not a headline, so headlinese would be inappropriate. “A guard of honor march as Crimeans celebrate” follows the same pattern as “A child plays as her mother watches.”

Comment: Attributive use of a (noun) phrase does not make that (noun) phrase an _adjective_. _Ice_ in _ice cream_ is not an adjective either...

Comment: The "sentence" (actually a fragment) is the caption for a picture of "a march".  The type of march, depicted in the photograph, is a "guard of honor" march. It is not required that the caption of a photograph be a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Would "A guard of honour marches to the eternal flame..."  be incorrect?  I'd accept either, thus admitting that the number of "guard of honour" was ambiguous.

I don't think it's necessary to concoct a parsing of that sentence where "march" isn't a verb, though it is just about possible to do so.